# Template/example Android project with actionbar and viewpager

Tags: android

I want to create an app. The main UI of my app is like facebook app or twitter app. That is, there is an action bar at top and there is a ViewPager below the action bar, so the user can swipe between pages in the ViewPager. Below is a screenshot of twitter main UI.

[image]

I don't want to create anything from scratch. I just wonder whether there is any template/sample Android project that implements this kind of UI, so I can copy the code to create the UI in my own app. My app is targeting api level 15 and above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
or look here for sample (library) https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip